# Variable number of columns in Python data, multiple .exp files

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, pandas

New Python user here.  The code I'm using is walking through a directory full of .exp files.  It's reading my data into an array.  The kicker is that these files have variable numbers of columns (some have 22, some have 32, but within each file, the lines all have the same number of columns).

```
    indata = np.genfromtxt(infile,delimiter = '\t',usecols=xrange(32),dtype=[('Cycle','i3'),('Time','S12'),('107Ag','float'), #...etc.
```

Is there a way to use pd.read to overcome this?  Or should I build some sort of conditional structure (seems clunky)?  Isn't there a way for the reader to break and continue with the next file when it encounters a null column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your data does not have headers and the first left columns of each file should align (i.e., if file A has 10 columns and file B has 15, then the first 10 of each file align with each other).  In that case:

```python
import glob
import pandas as pd

combined = []
for filepath in glob.glob('path/to/your/files/*.exp'):
    combined.append(pd.read_table(filepath, sep='\t', header=None))
combined = pd.concat(combined, ignore_index=True)
```